# Access IPv6 server behind router with IPv4

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv6, ssh-tunnel, ipv4

An IPv4 client in Germany should access an IPv6 server in the USA. This server is in a private home with a common home-router.

If it was an IPv4 server, I would just configure NAT and port forwarding to access the server, but in this case I also have the IPv4/IPv6 problem.

My idea (I did not try it yet) is, to establish two SSH tunnels to a third server from both, the client and the server. I don't know if that would work.

```
IPv4-Client <===SSH-Tunnel===>"My Ubuntu Proxy Server"<===>IPv6-Server
```

Could that work?
What better options are available?
Should I use OpenVPN instead of SSH-Tunnels?
Are there commercial solutions or providers? I mean, there are many VPN providers, so road warriors can browse the web securly, but in my case, I need to establish a connection between two road warriors.

Thank you for your input!
Best, schube

Comment: IPv6 works just fine with OpenVPN. That's what I'd do.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I know that OpenVPN works with IPv6. But does "bridging" IPv4 and IPv6 work?Would this be the right setup: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans ? Thanks

Comment: You'd provide v6 connectivity to your legacy v4 only host with openvpn. You should be able to modify the info here for your needs - https://www.jacobdevans.com/ipv6-openvpn-tunneling-with-asus-merlinwrt/

Comment: Does the IPv6 only ISP have a Teredo relay? One way to find an answer to that question is by visiting http://test-ipv6.netiter.dk/ from the IPv6 host and look for the teredo relay address in the results (I never got around to translate that page to English, but you should be able to find where it says teredo relay). If the IPv6 only ISP has a Teredo relay and isn't relying on third-party relays, then you can configure a Teredo client on the IPv4-only host.

Comment: i assume you have found a VPS provider that can give you both ipv4 and ipv6.   i suggest the OpenVPN method.  it is how i do it to get my v4 client to the v6 space.  it could get a v6-only client to the v4 space, too.  use a UDP link. a UDP reflector that can do dual-stack can let you do OpenVPN end-to-end. a TCP link can also be made to work (and *ssh* can be your link).

Comment: it look like *socat* can be used to make a UDP reflector to run on a dual-stack proxy to bridge between a v4-only host and a v6-only host.  then each end can run OpenVPN.

Answer (score 0):

There are two well defined IPv6 via IPv4 tunnels that I have used.

- 6in4 which allows point to point tunneling with static network blocks.  This is what my tunnel broker provides.
- 6to4 which generated IPv6 addresses based on your IPv4 address.  It is easy configure, but not as stable. This is how I originally configured IPv6 access.

Both mechanisms will have issues if your IPv4 address changes.  The would eliminate the need for a tunnel server.

Many VPNs support tunneling both IPv4 and IPv6 traffic.  Setting up a secure VPN on your tunnel server would provide flexibility for private solution.  This would enable you to firewall IPv6 on the tunnel server.  The above solutions should have IPv6 firewalled on both ends.

[rfc 7059](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7059) provides "A Comparison of IPv6-over-IPv4 Tunnel Mechanisms".  It includes additional mechanisms that I do not have experience with.

Comment: Are you sure you mean 6over4? Most tunnel providers use 6in4.

Answer (score 0):

Does your client in Germany support IPv6? Some ISPs in America are currently providing global IPv6 addresses to each client; for example Time Warner (now Spectrum) is giving each of my workstations a unique global address. Verizon I don't think does. So you'd have to check with the system in America, but dynamic dns supports IPv6. You may  not even need a complicated solution.